# How can I reduce the CPU usage of a program using Anonymous Pipes in a background worker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, pipe

I'm writing a program that uses anonymous pipes to communicate between different processes within our software suite.  We have a main executable (we'll call it the "Front End") that opens up separate executables ("Modules"), and the program I'm writing is basically going to act as an intermediary between all the different Modules by sending serialized messages from one to another to do different actions based on the message sent.

I have currently have 2 background workers that are constantly listening for messages sent from either the Front End (to open a Module) or Module (to send a message to another Module)

```
    private void bwModuleListener_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessMessage Message = null;
        AnonymousPipeServerStream ModuleReceiver = (AnonymousPipeServerStream)e.Argument;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        while (true)
        {
            Message = (ProcessMessage)bf.Deserialize(ModuleReceiver);
            if (Message != null)
            {
                bwModuleListener.ReportProgress(0, Message);
                Message = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void bwFrontEndListener_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessMessage Message = null;
        AnonymousPipeClientStream FrontEndReceiver = (AnonymousPipeClientStream)e.Argument;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        while (true)
        {
            Message = (ProcessMessage)bf.Deserialize(FrontEndReceiver);
            if (Message != null)
            {
                bwFrontEndListener.ReportProgress(0, Message);
                Message = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue with this is that the background workers are taking up a pretty substantial amount of the CPU (consistently 15% on my Quad-Core 3.4GHz machine).     I've tried sleeping the thread to slow the loop iterations, but the loops actually get hung up on the bf.Deserialize() call until an associated bf.Serialize() is called from the other end of the pipe.  Anyone have any suggestions of how I can make this more efficient?

Comment: Is the `Deserialize` call actually blocking when you call it and there's no message, or does it just return `null` immediately? Does the CPU usage change when you send more messages? Does it stay up when there's no messages? It really should be blocking, but... Have you tried some profiler to find out where the code is spending its time?

Comment: Any chance if zillions of exceptions are thrown in cycle?

Comment: @Luaan 1) Yes, it's definitely blocking on the Deserialize call  2) The CPU usage change is negligible whenever I send more messages  3) Yes it stays consistently around 15% regardless of whether or not there are messages  4) No I have tried using a profiler--I don't have much (if any) experience with them

Comment: @g.pickardou Nope, not exceptions thrown.  Just blocking at the Deserialize() call.

Comment: If Deserialize blocks then you must have something else in your app driving up usage.  Any other while loops and/or timers running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the loops actually get hung up on the bf.Deserialize" you mean that they block. This is normal since Deserialize will not complete until it gets the necessary data from the AnonymousPipeServerStream. As such it should not be consuming any CPU cycle.

Comment: So you're saying that my CPU usage is being driven by something else? *EDIT* This was actually the case--I found where the issue was occurring and have resolved it.  Thanks!

Comment: ...and the culprit was?